# Where to get realtime stock market data legally

Tags: data-request, finance

Can anybody point me to some service (free or paid) where my software can get real-time market data for analysis without recurring to web scraping? I'm interested in Latin American stock markets

Answer (score 2):

There is a free API service called [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co) that provides "free APIs for realtime and historical data on stocks, forex (FX), and digital/crypto currencies." However, there are some usage limits to the service, you can only 5 API requests per minute and 500 requests per day. The logistics of using the Alpha Vantage API are covered on their website. Furthermore, Alpha Vantage libraries on GitHub can be found [here](https://github.com/search?q=alpha+vantage).

Comment: FYI - it seems "realtime" in this case means updated every minute. "Their intraday data is realtime up to the current minute, which is fine for my research purposes but may not satisfy users who want to beat the market with millisecond precision." Source: https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage/issues/13

Comment: Similar platform is https://iextrading.com/developer/

Answer (score 0):

The only real-time trading data comes directly from the brokers or exchanges. To get access you need to be a licensed trader with them, and usually the live data in machine readable formats costs even more. Here's more [details](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/78643).

For real-time trading data (transactions) you should consider less traditional securities like blockchain currencies.